# SetBackgroundResource() delayed?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm implementing Simon Says in Android for a uni project, as part of an Audiogames suite application. I'm trying to generate a random sequence of 5 (just as a starting test) buttons playing and it's all going well except one thing: the buttons don't light up when they should (when their seed in the sequence is generated) but instead they do light up all together at the end of the generation.

Following the full code of my Java and XML (it's kind of a mess and incomplete so i'll point out to the parts that for me are troubling after)

Java Source

```
package it.unimi.di.lim.audiogames;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game2PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int mScore = 0;
    private LinkedList<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<>();

    private MediaPlayer mCMediaPlayer;
    private MediaPlayer mDMediaPlayer;
    private MediaPlayer mEMediaPlayer;
    private MediaPlayer mFMediaPlayer;

    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            releaseMediaPlayer(mp);
            turnOffButton(mp);
        }
    };

    private void releaseMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    private void turnOffButton(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Button mc_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c_button);
        Button md_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d_button);
        Button me_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e_button);
        Button mf_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.f_button);
        if(mp == mCMediaPlayer) {
            mc_button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game2_c_off));
        } else if (mp == mDMediaPlayer) {
            md_button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game2_d_off));
        } else if (mp == mEMediaPlayer) {
            me_button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game2_e_off));
        } else {
            mf_button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game2_f_off));
        }
    }

    private void playButton(int i) {
        char j;
        if(i==0)
            j='0';
        else if(i==1)
            j='1';
        else if(i==2)
            j='2';
        else
            j='3';
        Button mc_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c_button);
        Button md_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d_button);
        Button me_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e_button);
        Button mf_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.f_button);
        switch(j) {
            case '0':
                mc_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_c_on);
                //mCMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.c_sound);
                //mCMediaPlayer.start();
                //mCMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                 //   @Override
                 //   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                 //       mCMediaPlayer.release();
                 //   }
                //});
                break;
            case '1':
                md_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_d_on);
                //mDMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.d_sound);
                //mDMediaPlayer.start();
                //mDMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                //    @Override
                //    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //        mDMediaPlayer.release();
                //    }
                //});
                break;
            case '2':
                me_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_e_on);
                //mEMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.e_sound);
                //mEMediaPlayer.start();
                //mEMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                //    @Override
                //    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //        mEMediaPlayer.release();
                //    }
                //});
                break;
            case '3':
                mf_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_f_on);
                //mFMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.f_sound);
                //mFMediaPlayer.start();
                //mFMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                //    @Override
                //    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //        mFMediaPlayer.release();
                //    }
                //});
                break;
        }
    }

    private void createSequence(int i) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            int seed = rand.nextInt(4);
            temp.add(seed);
            playButton(seed);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        releaseMediaPlayer(mCMediaPlayer);
        releaseMediaPlayer(mDMediaPlayer);
        releaseMediaPlayer(mEMediaPlayer);
        releaseMediaPlayer(mFMediaPlayer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game2_play);

        Button mc_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c_button);
        Button md_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d_button);
        Button me_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e_button);
        Button mf_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.f_button);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Window window = this.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.game2Dark));
            window.setNavigationBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.game2Primary));
        }

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.game2Primary)));

        mc_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playButton(0);
                int check = temp.poll();
                if(check!=0) {
                    Intent gameOver = new Intent(Game2PlayActivity.this, Game2Activity.class);
                    gameOver.putExtra("score", mScore);
                    startActivity(gameOver);
                }
                if(temp.size() == 0) {
                    mScore++;
                    TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game2_score);
                    score.setText(Integer.toString(mScore));
                }
            }
        });

        md_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playButton(1);
                int check = temp.poll();
                if(check!=1) {
                    Intent gameOver = new Intent(Game2PlayActivity.this, Game2Activity.class);
                    gameOver.putExtra("score", mScore);
                    startActivity(gameOver);
                }
                if(temp.size() == 0) {
                    mScore++;
                    TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game2_score);
                    score.setText(Integer.toString(mScore));
                }
            }
        });

        me_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playButton(2);
                int check = temp.poll();
                if(check!=2) {
                    Intent gameOver = new Intent(Game2PlayActivity.this, Game2Activity.class);
                    gameOver.putExtra("score", mScore);
                    startActivity(gameOver);
                }
                if(temp.size() == 0) {
                    mScore++;
                    TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game2_score);
                    score.setText(Integer.toString(mScore));
                }
            }
        });

        mf_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playButton(3);
                int check = temp.poll();
                if(check!=3) {
                    Intent gameOver = new Intent(Game2PlayActivity.this, Game2Activity.class);
                    gameOver.putExtra("score", mScore);
                    startActivity(gameOver);
                }
                if(temp.size() == 0) {
                    mScore++;
                    TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game2_score);
                    score.setText(Integer.toString(mScore));
                }
            }
        });


        Button start_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.game2_start_button);
        start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createSequence(5);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML Source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Game1PlayActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/game2_score"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game2_score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:text="@string/game2_criteria"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/game2_start_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/game2_start"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="64dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/c_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/game2_c_off"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="@string/game2_c" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/d_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/game2_d_off"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="@string/game2_d" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/game2_e_off"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="@string/game2_e" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/f_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/game2_f_off"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="@string/game2_f" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

So basically what I'm trying to do is generating the sequence by clicking the button "Start" and here's the `onClickListener` (5 is just for testing purposes)

```
Button start_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.game2_start_button);
    start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createSequence(5);
        }
    });
```

This triggers the `createSequence()` method as follows

```
private void createSequence(int i) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        int seed = rand.nextInt(4);
        temp.add(seed);
        playButton(seed);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And so far all good. What I think is failing in my bad programming experience is the `PlayButton()` method

```
private void playButton(int i) {
    char j;
    if(i==0)
        j='0';
    else if(i==1)
        j='1';
    else if(i==2)
        j='2';
    else
        j='3';
    Button mc_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c_button);
    Button md_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d_button);
    Button me_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e_button);
    Button mf_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.f_button);
    switch(j) {
        case '0':
            mc_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_c_on);
            //mCMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.c_sound);
            //mCMediaPlayer.start();
            //mCMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            //    @Override
            //    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //        mCMediaPlayer.release();
            //    }
            //});
            break;
        case '1':
            md_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_d_on);
            //mDMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.d_sound);
            //mDMediaPlayer.start();
            //mDMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            //    @Override
            //    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //        mDMediaPlayer.release();
            //    }
            //});
            break;
        case '2':
            me_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_e_on);
            //mEMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.e_sound);
            //mEMediaPlayer.start();
            //mEMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            //    @Override
            //    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //        mEMediaPlayer.release();
            //    }
            //});
            break;
        case '3':
            mf_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_f_on);
            //mFMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.f_sound);
            //mFMediaPlayer.start();
            //mFMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            //    @Override
            //    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //        mFMediaPlayer.release();
            //    }
            //});
            break;
    }
}
```

The Audio Playback is commented but used to work just fine. It's really all about those SetBackgroundResource calls, they don't execute right away but only at the end of the for loop in the CreateSequence method.

If anyone wants to implement the whole project in Android Studio (unrecommended as it's probably very buggy), here it is (25 MB): http://www.mediafire.com/file/2c86sbe3rkb231d/AudiogamesSuite.zip

Thanks in advance

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EDIT - Managed to solve it thanks to Martin Pfeffer and some googling. Here's the updated code

```
private void createSequence(final int i) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Random rand = new Random();
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    final int seed = rand.nextInt(4);
                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                temp.add(seed);
                                playButton(seed);
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: why not to use just `switch(i)` ?

Comment: I couldn't use Integers as arguments and I thought that was the most simple way to solve it :)

Comment: You just need to say case 1 instead of case '1'

Comment: Should have paid more attention in my Programming class. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Add the `synchronized` specifier to the method.</strike>

```
private synchronized void createSequence(int i) {
        // allow only one thread to be executed
}
```

**Edit:**

Just saw you do not use separate threads.. So run this code to get the delay:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
          // do stuff             
      }}, 1000 * DELAY_IN_SECONDS);
```

Edit 2:

I think you are searching for something like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new MyThread((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).start();

    }


    class MyThread extends Thread implements Runnable {

        TextView textView;

        MyThread(TextView textView) {
            this.textView = textView;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnMainUiThread(new Callable() {
                    @Override
                    public Object call() throws Exception {
                        textView.setText("" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                        return null;
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        void runOnMainUiThread(final Callable callable) {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        callable.call();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("MyThread", "runOnMainUiThread: ", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any question, feel free to ask :)

Comment: I've read a bit around about handlers and seems like the problem relies in my Thread.sleep call, while Handlers should be able to circumvent that right?

Anyway thanks for the snippet i'll test it as soon as possible and will let you know!

Comment: It's not working...should I put the snippet into the createSequence function?

Comment: I can't understand how to exactly implement the second edit...?? Should I make a new Thread in the for loop of the createSequence method?